# Upload local stored image to server without plugin file transfer cordova

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, cordova, upload

I had been searching a lot and didn't find a simple solution.
I am developing a cordova application (Jquery / javascript) where I need to send all images stored in a directory named 'images' to  server without using the 'file transfer' plugin.
Is it possible to do this using only Jquery / Ajax and send via 'POST'method?
PS: each time (day) I need to send about 10 imagens to server. I am not using ionic.

Comment: Clarifying, this app only will run on Android system.

Comment: did you look into File API? (browser)

Comment: Hi Sergey. Thanks for your comment but Im so newer into this.. I had always made upload to server geting files via input type="file". I am completely lost about this. I will take a look into the File API.

Comment: maybe a form hidden with css, with a file input (its src containing the file) that gets submitted by js.

The server then should return `window.history.back()`